# How to get the JSON response from newman

Tags: node.js, json, postman, postman-collection-runner, newman

I tried to run the end point which is running fine on postman and I just exported as collection and running it through newman on JENKINS CI.

Command:

```
   newman run <POSTMAN_COLLECTION>.json -r json,cli
```

I'm getting the response.json file in the current directory as like below file:

[image]

I'm not able to see the response body inside the json file.

I'm googled but no luck. Is there anyway to get the response body for this postmand_collection? how can I achieve this?

I just want to get the response body as json file and I need to use it as request for other service.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could create a mini project and use Newman as a library and run it using a script. That way you could use the node `fs` module to write the response out to a file.

```
const newman = require('newman'),
        fs = require('fs');

newman.run({
    collection: '<Your Collection>'
}).on('request', function (error, data) {
    if (error) {
        console.error(error);
    }
    else {
        fs.writeFile(`response.json`, data.response.stream.toString(), function (error) {
            if (error) { 
                console.error(error); 
            }
        });        
    }
});
```

This script is using the Newman `.on('request')` event,  that will extract that information. If you wanted all the response bodies, you may need to modify this slightly and maybe use the `appendFileSync` to capture *all* the responses from the requests in the collection.